# JFlex Lexer. Multiline strings

Tags: string, multiline, lexer, jflex

I'm trying to parse some language with multiline string literals using JFlex.

Examples:

```
'''
this is a valid multiline string literal with 'quoted' word
'''
```

I've created two states:

```
%x IN_QUOTED_STRING
%x IN_MULTILINE_QUOTED_STRING
```

and created several macros and rules:

```
QUOTED_STRING_TAIL=[^\']* "'"
QUOTED_STRING_START="@"? "'"
MULTILINE_QUOTED_STRING_START = "@"? "'''"
MULTILINE_QUOTED_STRING_TAIL = [.]* "'''"

%%

<YYINITIAL> {MULTILINE_QUOTED_STRING_START} {yybegin(IN_MULTILINE_QUOTED_STRING);}
<YYINITIAL> {QUOTED_STRING_START} {yybegin(IN_QUOTED_STRING);}

<IN_QUOTED_STRING> {QUOTED_STRING_TAIL} {yybegin(YYINITIAL); return STRING;}
<IN_MULTILINE_QUOTED_STRING> {MULTILINE_QUOTED_STRING_TAIL} {yybegin(YYINITIAL); return STRING;}
```

But it doesn't work. I get "Error: could not match input"

Can anyone helps me with a proplem?

Comment: You're coming from Coursera, I suppose? :-)

Comment: works for me:

    QUOTED_LITERAL="'" ([^\\\'\r\n] | {ESCAPE_SEQUENCE} | (\\[\r\n]))* ("'"|\\)?
    ESCAPE_SEQUENCE=\\[^\r\n]

    ANY_ESCAPE_SEQUENCE = \\[^]

    THREE_QUO = (\"\"\")
    ONE_TWO_QUO = (\"[^\"]) | (\"\\[^]) | (\"\"[^\"]) | (\"\"\\[^])
    QUO_STRING_CHAR = [^\\\"] | {ANY_ESCAPE_SEQUENCE} | {ONE_TWO_QUO}
    TRIPLE_QUOTED_LITERAL = {THREE_QUO} {QUO_STRING_CHAR}* {THREE_QUO}?
    %%
    <YYINITIAL> {TRIPLE_QUOTED_LITERAL }{ return STRING; }
    <YYINITIAL> {QUOTED_LITERAL} { return STRING; }<code/>

Answer (score 1):

The OP wrote:

> works for me:
>
> ```
> QUOTED_LITERAL="'" ([^\\\'\r\n] | {ESCAPE_SEQUENCE} | (\[\r\n]))* ("'"|\)?
> ESCAPE_SEQUENCE=\[^\r\n] 
> ANY_ESCAPE_SEQUENCE = \[^] 
> THREE_QUO = (\"\"\") 
> ONE_TWO_QUO = (\"[^\"]) | (\"\[^]) | (\"\"[^\"]) | (\"\"\[^]) 
> QUO_STRING_CHAR = [^\\\"] | {ANY_ESCAPE_SEQUENCE} | {ONE_TWO_QUO}
> TRIPLE_QUOTED_LITERAL = {THREE_QUO} {QUO_STRING_CHAR}* {THREE_QUO}?
> %%
> <YYINITIAL> {TRIPLE_QUOTED_LITERAL }{ return STRING; } 
> <YYINITIAL> {QUOTED_LITERAL} { return STRING; }
> ```

Comment: ([answered in a comment, converted to community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))